# Changing value in JavaScript code/tag with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jinja2

I am stuck in an issue but I am not sure how to put this through. But I will try to explain.

When the page is loaded then I have this piece of code which is using jinja based place holder.

```
<div class="ui container">
            <div class="ui tiny blue header">{{ i.ProductName }}</div>
            <h5 class="ui grey header">{{ i.Category }}</h5>
            <h5 class="ui red header">₹{{ i.ActualPrice }} <s>₹{{ i.StrikedPrice }}</s> </h5>
            <script type="text/javascript">var lastid = "{{lid}}"</script>
          </div>
```

The above code is rendering fine and I am also getting the lastid to which I am making this as my global variable.

Now what happens is user clicks on "Load More" like so

```
<button v-on:click="loadmore" class="fluid ui button">Load More</button>
```

It then triggers a vue.js function like so.

```
 <script>
    var app5 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-5',
    delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
    data: {
        message: [],
    },
    methods: {
        loadmore: function () {
          axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/'+ld)
          .then(response => {this.message.push(...response.data);});
        }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

vue.js pushes my data in a mentioned ui container as shown below.

```
<div class="ui container">
              <div class="ui tiny blue header"> [[i.ProductName]]</div>
              <h5 class="ui grey header">[[i.Category]]</h5>
              <h5 class="ui red header">₹[[i.ActualPrice]] <s>₹[[i.StrikedPrice]]</s> </h5>
              <script type="text/javascript">lastid = [[lid]]</script>
            </div>
```

Notice there is a small javascript tag. The lastid which i am getting is not updating the global variable. The lastid should be updated with the latest ID. Is there a solution to this problem or perhaps any recommendation to change the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ld` to your app data and update it on response from axios:

```
data: {
    message: [],
    ld: 0, // default id you want to start it from
},
methods: {
    loadmore: function () {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/'+this.ld)
             .then(response => {
                 const messages = ...response.data;
                 this.message.push(messages);
                 this.ld = messages.pop().id;
             });

    }
}
```